# Maximum Likelihood Estimator $P(N=n) = (n+1)(1-p)^np^2$, $n = 1,2,3,\ldots$

Tags: probability

An experiment consists of giving a sequence of patients a risky treatment until 2 have died, and then recording $N$, the number who survived. If $p$ is the proportion killed by the treatment then the distribution of $N$ is given by:

$P(N=n) = (n+1)(1-p)^np^2$, $n = 1,2,3,\ldots$

a. Find a general form for the MLE for p.

b. The experiment is done in 8 hospitals and the observed values of $N$ are: 3, 0, 4, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3. Compute the estimate for $p$ derived in a.

So for part a. I end up getting $p = 4/(n+5)$. But then I don't know how to combine the observed values into one estimate. Did I maybe compute something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you confused $n$ which has the role of $x$ in this example, with the size of the sample which is usually denoted with $n$ (but not here, since as mentioned, $n$ is reserved to denote the values of the random variable $N$, which usually are denoted with $x$).

In any case, the likelihood function is $$\mathcal L(n;p)=\prod_{i=1}^{8}(n_i+1)(1-p)^{n_i}p^2=\left(p^2\right)^8(1-p)^{\sum_{i=1}^{8} n_i}\prod_{i=1}^{8}(n_i+1)$$ and the log-likelihood function is $$\ln \mathcal L(n;p)=16\ln p+\sum_{i=1}^{8} n_i\cdot\ln(1-p)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(n_i+1)$$ Its derivative (with respect to $p$) set equal to zero, yields $$0=\frac{16}{p}-\frac{1}{1-p}\sum_{i=1}^{8} n_i$$ which gives $$\hat p=\frac{16}{16+\sum_{i=1}^{8} n_i}$$ Since $\sum_{i=1}^{8}n_i=21$ according to your data, you have that the MLE $\hat p$ of $p$ is equal to $$\hat p= \frac{16}{16+21}=\frac{16}{37}$$

Comment: On your third line of work aren't you missing a $-1/(1-p)$ term multiplied with the summation part? Also this still doesn't really address the problem of finding a general form.

Comment: @EgoKilla Yes, that is a mistake, wait I will correct it

Comment: @EgoKilla Is it ok now?

Comment: Okay I think I get it now. The general form is $\hat p = 2(sample size)/(2*(sample size) + \sum_{i=1}^{sample size}n_i)$? The correction seems good.

Comment: @EgoKilla Yes, you forgot a 2 in the denominator before samplesize.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for clearing all that up.

Comment: You are welcome mate!